# Sort items in the ListBox using XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-8.1

I have a ListBox with Items and I need to sort them.  I know that I can sort the data in DataContext, but I want to try to implement it using XAML.

I have found this solution for WPF:

```
 var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(DataContext);
 view.SortDescriptions.Clear();
 if(_sortField.SelectedValue != null)
      view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription((string)
       _sortField.SelectedValue,_ascending.IsChecked == true ?
       ListSortDirection.Ascending :
       ListSortDirection.Descending));
```

but I don't have GetDefaultView() method for CollectionViewSource. Is there any way to adapt this XAML to Windows 8.1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've found, `CollectionViewSource` has a different implementation in WinRT (Windows 8.1) apps.  But the `ICollectionView` interface. is also different.  The [WPF ICollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview(v=vs.110).aspx) supports sorting, grouping and filtering, while the [WinRT implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.collectionviewsource(v=win.10).aspx) only supports grouping.

You can get the `CollectionView` with this code.

```
var source = SourceRepository.GetSamples();

var cvs = new CollectionViewSource();
cvs.Source = source; 
var view = cvs.View;
this.DataContext = view;
```

But you won't be able to use `view.SortDescriptions` because `SortDescriptions` is not part of the class definition.

Of course you can always use LINQ to sort and filter.